# PCB - Altium designer resistor voltage divider calculation

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, voltage-divider

[image: Calculate voltage divider for 1.8V output voltage]

Good evening,
I have a problem, I'm not really studying EE or know anything about EE, but I'm doing an optional course in PCB design, in my schematic document, I have a place (picture), where I have this text written next to it:

> Calculate voltage divider for 1.8V output voltage

I really have no idea how to do this, and I might find resources how to calculate it, I'm a bit scared I might find a wrong answer. I would like to know for sure, so that's why I asked here.

If anyone could help I'd be happy. Also, if this picture isn't enough to calculate, I can edit and paste a bigger picture of the schematic. Thank you in advance.
[image: Even bigger picture]

Comment: Calculations your current (I = V/Rtotal) then calculate voltage on R11: V = I * R11. This is called ohm's law: V = IR

Comment: Why are you afraid to get the wrong answer in a course?

Comment: it's a big pcb project, I think one mistake could mothball into many mistakes? I don't know. As I've said, I don't know much about this, that makes me not confident in making bold moves. EDIT: (big for me)

Comment: @BenCruel I think you mean “snowball”.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a resistive voltage divider is **Vout = (Vin * R2) / (R1 + R2)**. R2 is the "lower resistor" in the divider, and R1 is the "upper resistor". Vout is your desired output voltage and Vin is your supply voltage. You can pick either R1 or R2 and use basic algebra to solve for the other resistor. Do keep in mind that lower resistor values will draw excessive current in-circuit, so generally shoot for tens or hundreds of kilohms for your chosen resistor values.

Comment: Vout in this situation is 1.8V?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: "[...] so generally shoot for tens or hundreds of kilohms for your chosen resistor values" - bad advice, check the requirements of the next stage.

Comment: @awjlogan True, hence the word **generally**. Obviously if you're putting a voltage divider on a low-impedance input of, say, an ADC, then you're going to have to rethink things a bit. But with the generic question I gave a generic answer.

Comment: @DerStrom8 could you invite me into a chat, and I would send a bigger picture? Maybe you could give me a more specific answer. If you have the time of course.

Comment: @BenCruel Is there any particular reason you can't add the bigger picture to your original question? It would be much better to get more than just one extra set of eyes on it.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I'm not sure if I know how much is enough. I added a bigger picture, let me know if it helps, or if I should add an even bigger picture.

Comment: @BenCruel Make sure you read the datasheet. It provides a lot of useful information. On Page 14 under the "Adjustable Operation" heading it states: *"The value of R1 should be no greater than 250k
to minimize errors in the output voltage caused by the
ADJ pin bias current"*. Additionally, Page 18 states: *"The top resistor of the resistor divider must be chosen to
limit the current into the ADJ pin to less than 5mA when
the ADJ pin is at 7V. The 13V difference between output
and ADJ pin divided by the 5mA maximum current into the
ADJ pin yields a minimum top resistor value of 2.6k."*

Comment: So based on the datasheet, you must choose a value for R1 between 2.6k and 250k.

Comment: With voltage dividers I like to take the ratio of voltages (which is, of course, equal to the ratio of resistors) as it makes choosing standard parts easier; if I have a feedback pin at 1.2V and an output at 1.8V, then the ratio is 0.5 of top to bottom part.

Comment: I'm really lost. Did the bigger picture help?

Comment: @BenCruel Yes it did, and based on the "bigger picture" I see you're using the voltage divider to adjust the output voltage of an LT1763. I then looked at the datasheet for this part (which you should have done from the very start) and read about  how to calculate the values for the voltage divider connected to the ADJ pin.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have added the "bigger picture" the answer to the question is easier to get.
What you want is the values for the feedback partition on a LT1763.

The first step to take is to look up the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1763fh.pdf), and scroll all the way to page 14, where it shows the formula on how to get the values you want.

AS you already have another LT1763 used below the one you want to calculate the value for, you can take one of the values from the partition of the second one, and go from there.

For example R9 could be 10k, just like R14, and you just need to calculate R11.
without doing the calculation, I estimate that ballpark value of R11 should be in the region of a 20k, but I let you do the fine tuning.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I'm looking at the fact that there are another LT1763 below, I saw that there's another one and I didn't put it in the screenshoot. Could you look at the newly added picture? Maybe that will make everything even more clear. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Adding a third regulator doesn't change the question or the answer.
Have you tried to plug the values I have given you in the formula from the datasheet?

Comment: I wasn't able to calculate the second resistor. Actually, I'm not sure which values are which, everything to me seems very vague.

Comment: maybe you could calculate the exact value? I don't want to make a mistake.